# Raising Level Of Concrete Floor to Equal Existing Tile In The Same Room

Tags: flooring, installation

We would like to install vinyl luxury planks in our dining room.  We have removed the 20 year old carpet, padding and tacking strips so that the concrete slab is exposed.  The room was laid out with a ceramic tile pathway from the front door through the dining room and into the kitchen and we want to lay the lvp over the entire area without the removing all of the tiles.  How should we raise up the concrete slab side of the room to meet the tile floor so that we can lay the lvp in the entire room?  We will face the same situation with the entry way and our living room as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could flood the non-tile area with Self Leveling Compound.  This is often done for glue down hardwood floor installs - not cheap or easy but can be done.

That said I'd sooner just use a rotary hammer with a tile removal blade and pull all the tile than go through the expense and labor of flooding with SLC.

Comment: ***Far less work*** to remove the tile - and less expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this.  Was really hoping to avoid the mess of taking up the tile but looks like we'll probably have to take up the tile.